# Error code 134 ONLY During Release Mode on function return

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, eigen

I'm running a function that implements moving obstacles that I've encapsulated in an object. When I run 6 obstacles, there are no problems, but at 8, the function throws error code 134. When I run debug on release mode, it shows "symbol stub for: __stack_chk_fail".
I am not using any pointers, so I don't think I'm freeing something twice. I am using the Eigen library.

Here is the function call:
`MatrixXd result=r.dynamic_rrt_star_roam(m, end,n_obs,1);`

and here are the last few lines of that function:

```
    MatrixXd res=MatrixXd::Zero(path_traveled.size(),6);
    for(int i=0;i<path_traveled.size();i++){
        res.row(i)=path_traveled[i];
    }
    return res;
```

I have no idea where to begin with this, as I'm not using any pointers and I'm not getting any error messages. Additionally, this is not a problem when the parameter n_obs is 6, but anything greater is an issue.

I tried increasing the stack and I double checked for any pointers. Additionally, I can print all of these variables out before I return anything. My codebase is fairly large so I'm not sure sharing all of it would be useful.

Comment: Sounds like you may have [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) somewhere.

Comment: You have probably "smashed" the stack; written to memory outside the local variables. It may not have happened here - this is just where the runtime detected it. Triple-check any array indexing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.